# Postgresql Instantiating and Referencing Foreign Keys

Tags: postgresql

So I have 4 tables in my database and each table has a `serial` ID element. However, some tables use these IDs as references and I'm not sure how to create all these at once, without errors occurring when two people access this service at the same time.

Basically, my thoughts are to generate the blank rows with new IDs, like

```
INSERT INTO table1 DEFAULT VALUES;
```

Then reference the largest ID for the most recent and make my foreign keys reference the largest ID. However, I see this being trouble if two people want to access this service at the same time and one person sets up a new row while the other person is looking for their reference ID. Is there a less error-prone way to handle referencing these IDs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find the id value using `RETURNING id`, so you can use that value for `FOREIGN KEYS`

Comment: Thanks! Seems to be just what I was looking for. I'm new to SQL in general and didn't seem to see anything on this yet so far.